# Error after updating php elasticsearch-php from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2

Tags: php, elasticsearch, guzzle

The following code worked before updating elasticsearch-php from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2:

```
$client = new Elasticsearch\Client();

// Index Settings
$indexParams['index'] = 'address';

// Example Index Mapping
$myTypeMapping = array(
    '_source' => array(
        'enabled' => true
    ),
    'properties' => array(
        'post_code' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        )
    )
);

$indexParams['body']['mappings']['postcode'] = $myTypeMapping;

// Create the index
$client->indices()->create($indexParams);
```

The error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message
>   'Client error response [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request
>   [url] http://localhost:9200/address' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\locatr\vendor\guzzle\http\Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException.php:43
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\locatr\vendor\guzzle\http\Guzzle\Http\Message\Request.php(145):
>   Guzzle\Http\Exception\BadResponseException::factory(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest),
>   Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::onRequestError(Object(Guzzle\Common\Event),
>   'request.error',
>   Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\locatr\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php(164):
>   call_user_func(Array, Object(Guzzle\Common\Event), 'request.error',
>   Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\locatr\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Symfony\Component\Eve
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\locatr\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection.php
>   on line 266

Are there any changes between these versions that would break the code? There is nothing as far as I could see from the documentation.

Or is there an issue with the code sample? or is something else more likely?

Comment: Can you check the Elasticsearch logs to see if you can get more details about this error ?

Comment: There is nothing really related in the log. 

I'm trying to figure it out at the moment and it seems the error is generated when trying to create an index that already exists. Is this what it should do and how do I catch the error?

Comment: If the index already exist Elasticsearch sends a 400 response, so this is the expected behavior. You may check before if the index already exists.

Comment: Thanks, just found that in that in IndicesNamespace. Seems to have solved the problem, not sure why I didn't get the error before though.